# data from model to controller and back to model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
<?php //controller
function notif()
{
    $condition = $this->business_model->get_condition();
    $this->data['query'] = $this->business_model->data_pagination_admin($condition);
        $this->load->view('student_result',$this->data);
}
?>

<?php //model
function get_condition()
{

  $this->db->select('condition');
  $this->db->from('staff');
  $query = $this->db->get(); 
  return $query->result_array();
}

function data_pagination_admin($condition)//notif function
{
    //...........
    $this->db->where('flag','n');
    //$user_id = $this->session->userdata('condition');
    $this->db->where($condition,$user);//notice parameter condition
    $this->db->order_by('next_date','asc');
    $query = $this->db->get('student',10,0);
    return $query->result_array();
}

 /*im getting error :"Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM (`student`) JOIN `status_table` ON `student`.`stud_id` = 
   `status_table`.`stud_id` WHERE `status_table`.`next_date` > '2013-06-09 23:59:59'
 AND     `flag` = 'n' AND **`0` = Array ORDER** BY `next_date` asc LIMIT 10"*/


?>
```

1.im geting value from model to controller and passing it to controller to another 
function but getting error.

2.controller->get_condition->controller->data_pagination_admin()

3.the get condition function will return just a string thats all

Comment: What does get_condition() return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_condition`currently returns an array; try the code below:

```
function get_condition()
{
$user = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
$this->db->select('condition');
$this->db->from('staff');
$this->db->where('user_id',$user );
$query = $this->db->get(); 
$result = $query->row_array();
return $result['condition'];
}
```

Edit: looks like your $user var in that where clause is also an array.

Comment: it now gives error -"Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_result::result_row() in C:\xampp\htdocs\business\application\models\business_model.php "

Comment: *actually as i have said in question the model will return only value from 1 row as data not an array as u can see                                 *the $user has only a single data from a single row a name thats all and the condition returns similar data

Comment: My mistake, use `$query->row_array()`(see updated answer above).

Comment: As per your code, `get_condition()`does this: `return $query->result_array();`--> that's returning an array, not a single value.

Comment: i tried $query->row_array() its still giving error "SELECT * FROM (`student`) JOIN `status_table` ON `student`.`stud_id` = `status_table`.`stud_id` WHERE `status_table`.`next_date` > '2013-06-09 23:59:59' AND `flag` = 'n' AND ` = 'suresh@griantek.com' ORDER BY `next_date` asc LIMIT 10"

Comment: Why did you remove the where clause from your `get_condition`function in your question? It was there when I first looked.

Comment: In get_condition, instead of returning anything, try `print_r($result); exit;`right before the return line. Does that give you anything, or an empty array?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [condition] => some_id ) ) ->its returning the correct data

Comment: "some_id" is a number? So you'd have a sql string such as `AND '1' = 'suresh@griantek.com'`. So your table column name would be an int??

Comment: no its a string that is what i want, ill cheack where(some_id = user_id) some_id is column name in table                                *so i want to select rows in where the column some_id is a particular value

Comment: Looks like you're still using `result_array()`instead of `row_array()`; your print_r should give `Array
(
    [condition] => some_id
)` (Note that there's no [0] index)

Comment: ya thank you it worked ,so can u tell me the difference in usage of 'result_array()' and 'row_array()'

Comment: Glad to help. `result_array()` is to be used when you expect to have multiple rows returned from the query; if you need just one row from the query, use `row_array()`. If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as such by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: so if i use 'result_array()' in my code how should i get the value of 'condition' column - if u feel my question did make sense and would be useful to others just vote it up

Comment: `$result = $query->result_array(); return $result[0]['condition'];` Note that if your query returns multiple rows, this will only return the first row found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var_dump()` to see what the value of certain variables and results are. You shouldn't use `$query->row()` since it will only return 1 row. i suggest you should iterate the array like so:

```
foreach($query->result() as $result)
    {
    $this->data['query'].=$result
    }
```